# Understanding the MSDN _beginthreadex function example

Tags: return-value, msdn, beginthread, function-exit

There's this function on `_beginthreadex` [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb%28VS.80%29.aspx):

```
unsigned __stdcall SecondThreadFunc( void* pArguments )
{
    printf( "In second thread...\n" );

    while ( Counter < 1000000 )
    Counter++;

    _endthreadex( 0 );
    return 0;
}
```

I know you can get the value returned by `_endthreadex` with the function `GetExitCodeThread`, but how do you get the value returned by `return`?

Another question: doesn't `_endthreadex` end the thread, why did they put a `return 0` after that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return 0` is there just to make the compiler happy. `_endthreadex` does not return.

Answer (score 1):

In this snippet the `return` statement is indeed only to make the compiler happy. However, in fact, you don't need to call `_endthreadex` as it is called internally by `_beginthreadex` after you return from your thread function. And it passes your return value to `_endthreadex` (or `ExitThread`, from it).

See [Raymond Chen's article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171115-00/?p=97405)